# How to plot two geoms side-by-side for same categorical in R? (errorbarjitter)

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I came across what I found to be some helpful figures by David L. Stern at [howtogiveatalk.com](http://www.howtogiveatalk.com/blog/principle-3-show-your-data) that have a jitterplot next to a mean/sd summary for each categorical variable.

Here is the first example from the page linked above [image]

I spent some time trying to find similar figures online and couldn't.

I'm not sure which software and packages he used to create these figures (UPDATE: [David Stern responded](https://twitter.com/David_L_Stern/status/708326232539017217) and explained that he uses a [custom built Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33658-errorbarjitter) function). I am most familiar with R and ggplot2 and figure it must be possible to create something similar using these tools. I tried to jump right in and make it but can't figure out where to go from here.

How I got started:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(a = rnorm(100, mean = 0.75, sd  = 0.5), b = rgamma(100, shape = 0.75, scale = 0.5), c = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.6))
df <- gather(df)
df.sum <- df %>% group_by(key) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value), sd = sd(value))

ggplot(data = df.sum, aes(x = key)) + 
  geom_jitter(data = df, aes(y = value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = mean)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = key, y = mean, ymin = (mean - sd), ymax = (mean + sd))) +
  theme_bw()
```

Which produces the following graph:
[image]

The code is pretty rough, but gets most of the way there. I can't figure out how to move the geom_point and geom_linerange beside the jitter, though.

So how can this figure be made in R (preferably using ggplot2)?

Comment: @Silverfish I thought this would fall under the category of "visualizing data," but I now that I see the distinction made in your link, I can see that it's a coding question. If that's where it belongs and you could migrate it for me, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @RonLevitin A good place to ask questions like this is http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ggplot2

Comment: @Silverfish great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out! I'll post the answer here for future reference and for anyone else wanting to make a similar plot.

The key for me came down to converting the x-axis from a factor to a numeric in order to apply the shift.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(125)

df <- data_frame(Normal = rnorm(100, mean = 0.5, sd  = 0.5), 
                 Gamma = rgamma(100, shape = 0.5, scale = 0.5), 
                 Bimodal = c(rnorm(50, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.15), rnorm(50, mean = 0.9, sd = 0.15))
                 )
df <- gather(df)
df.sum <- df %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value), sd = sd(value))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = key, y = value)) + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), shape = 1, size = 3.5) + 
  geom_pointrange(data = df.sum, aes(x = as.numeric(key)+0.3, y = mean, ymin = (mean - sd), ymax = (mean + sd))) +
  geom_point(data = df.sum, aes(x = as.numeric(key)+0.3, y = mean), size = 3.5) +
  theme_bw() + xlab("") + ylab("Arbitrary Units")
```

[image: Example plot]

It would be great if this code could be adapted into a ggplot extension to make this into a simple geom. I might take on the challenge myself if I can find the time.

Answer (score 2):

#### Fairly straightforward without ggplot2

```
x<-0.5+runif(100,-0.2,0.2)
y<-rbind(rnorm(100,1,1),rgamma(100,1,1),rbinom(100,1,0.5)*2+rnorm(100,0,0.2))
for (j in 0:2){
  if (j==0){plot(x,y[1,],xlim=c(0,4),ylim=c(-1,5),xlab="",ylab="Arbitrary Units",xaxt="n",bty="n",col="gray50")}
  else{points(x+j, y[j+1,],col="gray50")}
  points(j+0.9, mean(y[j+1,]),pch=19)
  arrows(j+0.9,mean(y[j+1,])-sd(y[j+1,]),j+0.9,mean(y[j+1,])+sd(y[j+1,]), angle=90,length=0)
  } # for j categories
axis(1,seq(0.5,2.5, by=1),tick=F,labels=c("Normal","Gamma","Bimodal"))
```

[image]

Comment: It'd be nice to post a picture of this, but I don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: For translucent points, such as in the Stern graph, set col=rgb(0,0,0,alpha=100,max=255) and adjust transparency with the alpha parameter.

Comment: I tried to add the picture, but needs to be "peer reviewed" on the site before it is made public. Thanks for the example in base R! Perhaps because I'm more familiar with the ggplot2 syntax, I find it more intuitive and less cryptic.